# xcode 8 Quick Help inspector link not working

Tags: user-interface, xcode8

After upgrading to Xcode 8, i cannot use the Quick Help inspector anymore.

[image]

For example, i have a `saveNewNote` function in my `MainViewController.swift` file. If i click the function title somewhere in the code, it allows quick scrolling to that function by clicking the link in the attached image. It is very convenient if you have a large number of lines in your code.

Restart Xcode and MacBook did not help.
Is there some settings needed to be changed to be able to use this feature again?

Comment: I have the same problem. Some solutions from previous Xcode mishaps say that `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode WebKitJavaScriptEnabled` will solve it; however, it didn't seem to work on my end. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: As i understand, this solution is for disappearing quick help popup if you option click some method to see its description - that works as it should. Anyway thanks for your comment, it gives some hints that its maybe connected with some javascript settings.

Comment: I have sent a bug report to Apple. I guess it will take them years to reply. So by now I'm suffering with cmd+f to find my methods in the files.